# dataLabel text align in highchart

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart

I want to dynamically align the dataLabel in center of two bars.

The data which is visible dynamically appears either for green or the blue bar by using :

```
dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.point.avg;
                }
            }
```

I dont want to use x and y attributes, as data can appear for any of the bar. Hope below mentioned image gives you a clear picture.

[image]

Note: The value of avg_fare does not represent the bar's value.

Can anyone help me to achieve this usecase?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [dataLabels.y](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.dataLabels.y) parameter to offset the label into the position you desire.

```
      series: [{
            data: series1,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,                    
                y: -14 // move this down
            }
        }, {
            data: series2,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,                    
                y: 14 // move this one up
            }
        }]
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbCn8/1/).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

enable datalables only for one. and disable for all the remaining ones.
position that single label as you want by seetting x and y Values

```
            dataLabels: {
                align:'left',
                enabled: true,                    
                x: 20,
                y: -10
            },
```

you can refer this as example : http://jsfiddle.net/fMdk3/

Hope this will help you

Comment: I appreciate your approach. I tried the same thing, what is not apt over here is the values for the both bar differs, which we can see in the example you posted. Check 'Apr' in your example, dataLabel collapses.

Comment: that is because the labels overflowed the plot area, this can be controlled like in here http://jsfiddle.net/fMdk3/1/

Comment: Yes that is true. but what if the value of series 1 data is smaller than series 2 data. Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/fMdk3/2/)

Comment: I've checked marks answer that solves your question. thats perfect